# Is There A Hook To Process The Content Of The Text Widget?

Tags: plugin-development, customization, widgets, widget-text

Is there any filter which can be used in a plugin to process the content of the text widget before it is rendered?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Filter

1. widget_text (for the text)
2. widget_title (for the title)

## Example

```
function add_smiley($content) {
$new_content = '';
$new_content.= $content . ':)';
return $new_content;
}   
add_filter('widget_text', 'add_smiley');
```

Note that this works only for the content so not if you have a widget with only a title.

## Reference

1. http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Widgets
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1385954/do-wordpress-widget-or-sidebar-hooks-exist
3. https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=wordpress+widget

Comment: Do you know any filter for custom widget?

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to run a filter on `widget_text`. The text widget is the only one that calls the `widget_text` hook.

http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.0.1/wp-includes/default-widgets.php

Line 380 ..

```
$text = apply_filters( 'widget_text', $instance['text'], $instance );
```

So in short, Yes! Would be the direct answer to your question. Hope that helps... :)