# How to use the filter 'widget_text' to a particular text widget with id

Tags: filters, widget-text

I have a sidebar with 10+ text widgets serving advertisements. Now I want to filter a particular text widget in a single post if that post has a data in meta field. I searched a lot and found [Is There A Hook To Process The Content Of The Text Widget?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4336/is-there-a-hook-to-process-the-content-of-the-text-widget/4337#4337). But this changes the content of all text widgets. How can I change a particular text widget?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it default text widget? If yes, then I don't think there is a way.

Why don't you create a custom text widget? And before echoing output process the text whatever you wants to do?

The logic is, you will create another widget, that will take some text (or html?) and you will process that text, add some data what you want and show as output :)

Comment: Great! Your Solution works form me. This is what I need.