# Hook called before text widget save

Tags: php, plugin-development, customization, widgets, widget-text

I want to know which hook/action is called just before the Text Widget content and title is stored in the database. I googled alot but could not able to get the hook name.

What I want is whenever a text widget save button is trigger (in admin panel) I want to apply my custom content customize function and the return the updated content so that WP can saves it.

**Please Note**: My question is not a duplicate of [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/4336/103815), because it deals with filter and I'm looking for hook or action. It can be a one solution but is not a good solution in my case, because it'll a time consuming.
**For example:** I have 10 active text widget in my sidebar and for every page hit on each widget render `widget_text` will be called. So I'm looking for a better solution.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: grrr you complain about the answer before it was even given :((. In general if you need different behaviour you should write your own "text widget" as there are all kinds of hooks triggered when a widget is saved but they are not likely to be easily used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you're after here, another options maybe possible, but there's e.g. [this](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/widget_update_callback/) hook:

```
/**
 * Filters a widget's settings before saving.
 *
 * Returning false will effectively short-circuit the widget's ability
 * to update settings.
 *
 * @since 2.8.0
 *
 * @param array     $instance     The current widget instance's settings.
 * @param array     $new_instance Array of new widget settings.
 * @param array     $old_instance Array of old widget settings.
 * @param WP_Widget $this         The current widget instance.
 */
 $instance = apply_filters( 
    'widget_update_callback', 
    $instance, 
    $new_instance, 
    $old_instance, 
    $this 
);
```

Here's an example how we can target *Text* widgets and modify the `text` input field, when they are updated:

```
add_filter( 'widget_update_callback', function( $instance, $new, $old, $obj )
{
    if( 'text' === $obj->id_base && ! empty( $instance['text'] ) )
    {
        // Warning this overrides the widget instance text input:
        // $instance['text'] = 'override text';
    }

    return $instance;
}, 10, 4 );
```